# Customization of Hibernate sequence generation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one hibernate sequence, that generates all sequence-numbers in my app. When I generate the schemas from hibernate (target Oracle10), it genererates:

```
create sequence hibernate_sequence;
```

I would like to change the configuration of the sequence. I have to use something like:

```
create sequence hibernate_sequence order nocache;
```

I don't like to change the generated scripts, everytime I create them. Where can I customize the sequence generated by hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom sequence generator. See http://www.hibernate.org/296.html for details.